# When to use inner classes?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Usage of inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049718/usage-of-inner-class)

Dear folks,

I am relatively new to java i am studying inner classes. i have read a little bit though, but i am not getting in what situation inner classes come handy for a programmer

Thanks in advance
Vinayak Jog

Comment: Can you answer my question: How many times this question is asked in the last 24 hours???

Answer (score 5):

Example : 
You have a class Car , which contains lots of objects.. One of them is really technical, and there are maybe 1-2 people in the world who know what this mysterious and wierd object is. Lets call this object type **T**

Now, if you are going to explain the class Car to anyone who does not know about **T**. Most of them understand that there is something that performs a useful function : *F* ,  but they have no idea that there is something called **T**.

This is what an inner class is, something that is required for the class that the inner class is in, but not required to be known by anyone else :)

Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Inner classes are useful , when u don't want to expose the class existence to anything outside the containing class. I usually use Inner classes in making things more secure.

Also inner classes are used extensively when the class has no meaning outside the containing class, also if u need same name classes having different functionality or instances for different classes (the classes containing inner classes).