# why do we go for inner class or what's the main advantage of using inner class

Tags: java, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Usage of inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049718/usage-of-inner-class)

I was looking for main reason for which, **inner class** will be used, i got most common answer everywhere.. **`Due to re-usability of the existing code`**. But, we can achieve this by define one class outside of the class too. isn't ??

```
class MyOuterClass {
    private class MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mTts.speak(words.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        }
    }

    // later (inside some method)...
        speakBtn.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener());
}
```

here `MyOnClickListener` is the inner class, later creating the object same way as we do for normal class `new MyOnClickListener()`. So, what is the main difference, for the reason, it has been introduced.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049718/usage-of-inner-class

Comment: some functionality which is best represented as an object, but which is only meaningful within the context of another object, `which does not necessarily need to be exposed to the outside world`

Comment: What do you mean by `inner` class if in your example it is `inner` class what you use? May be you mean ANONYMOUS inner class? Anyway, no-nstatic inner class has hidden member of outer class type and can use it's members. Outer class or static class are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you defined this **inner** class (non-static) allows to access members of the **outer** class. This means in general a rather private use within the outer class

An other reason to use inner classes is to make clear that the class is intended to be used by and with the outer class.

A **static** inner class could by accessed by any other.

Comment: so which means.. it is similar to private class, which is defined outside the class. But, in this case, it won't be accessible by any class. So, inner class introduced. isn't ..??

Answer (score 1):

Inner classes should be used to group logically related classes together. Of course, nobody is forcing you to make certain classes inner classes - you can very well define them in a separate file (unless you want to make them private, which could certainly be a possibility). An example is the [`LinkedList`](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/LinkedList-source.html) class in `java.util`. There is an inner class called `Entry` which serves as the nodes for the list - and will only be used inside the `LinkedList` class, so it is defined as an inner class.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with all other answers, but I just want to add one note. In case of your question, I prefer anonymous classes (I suppose you instantiate MyOnClickListener class just once), its looks cleaner and more concise:

```
speakBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
      mTts.speak(words.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
  }
});
```